# How to apply scrollView and pageControl to TableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I want to  apply scrollView and pageControl to TableviewCell but i don't know how to do it. I tried making a xibfile and write the scrollview and pagecontrol to xibfile's swift file but i made it all by code and it seemed that it didn't worked. I first made a mistake by adding the subview from a cell name to a label that is on the scrollview but i solved it by adding changing it to: `contentView.addSubview(mainViewLabel)` 
but it also didn't work.
Can somebody give me a sample code or a way to do it by the interface builder?

If it is better to find a problem by looking at my code i will edit my question so please tell me.